# Is postfix increment and decrement left to right associative or the contrary?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

In "C++ primer 5th edition" on `page 228` The table `Table 4.4. Operator Precedence` shows operators and associativitiy of operands.

What I am confused about is in this table says that Prefix increment/decrement is Right-To-Left associative and also Postfix increment/decrement also Right-To-Left So there's the letter "R" that means right to left. But in `www.cppreference.com` I see that postfix increment/decrement are Left-To-Right associative.

If someone makes things clear up through giving an example containing Compound expression, then is really appreciated.

Comment: Everybody who wrote code where it matters should be at least penalized.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how a unary postfix operator could be right associative. It makes my brain hurt.

Comment: @FredLarson yea `ptr[i]++` would work pretty strange way

Comment: You can always just go to the source: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.post#1.sentence-1

Comment: As I understand it, associativity is a property of binary operators. Perhaps you could give an example expression that would have different (and sane!) evaluations for different associativities of the postfix increment operator?

Answer (score 5):

[The C++ grammar](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/gram.expr) defines a postfix expression like this:

```
postfix-expression:
    primary-expression
    ...
    postfix-expression ++
    ....
```

In parsing `a ++ ++`, `a` is a primary-expression, so `a ++` is a postfix-expression. The final `++` applies to the result of that postfix-expression.

In short, `++` groups left to right.

The same thing applies to all of what we usually think of as postfix operators: they apply to a postfix-expression, so they group left to right.

As mentioned in a comment, going the other way would make `ptr[i]++` rather funky.

Looking at a (probably illegal) PDF version of that book that I found online, I suspect the the entries for postfix++ and postfix-- are cut-and-paste typos. Both of those operators are supposedly described on page 147, as are prefix++ and prefix--, but the only discussion there is about prefix++ and prefix--.

Comment: Thank you first. Second: The very book on O'relleiy https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/c-primer-fifth/9780133053043/ch04lev1sec12.html#ch04lev1sec12" is with the same mistake. It is not only about Postfix incr/decr but also about explicit cast...

Answer (score 0):

There's no book safe from Errata. Each version of a book adds some enhancements and corrects some mistakes. The author is always appreciating Errata reporting. Anyway: The post-fix increment and -decrement are Left-To-Right associative.

```
int x = 5;
x++;
```

As you can see from the expression above: the operand `x`is at the `lhs` of the operator `++` thus you easily can understand it.

```
++x;
```

Now the operand `x` is on the right thus Pre-increment/decrement is Right-To-Left.

Answer (score -1):

Prefix operators are Right to Left associative:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Neither C++ Primer 5th edition from Prata nor from Lippman have any operator priority table on page 228.

Comment: I said Postfix increment and decrement. Artur I have the "C++ Primer, Fifth Edition Stanley B. Lippman Josée Lajoie Barbara E. Moo" did you check it? on page 228 not 288?

Comment: Checked it many times. Lippman 5th edition page 228 is about '6.3.3 Returning pointer to an array' and in 4th edition of the same book on same page there is "7.1.2 Function Parameter List" section. Are you saying about english versions of the book?

Comment: Yes. the book is in English.

Comment: What is its original language?

Comment: would you find the table of "operators and precedence and associativity" in your book?

Comment: 4th edition (isbn: 0201721481) page 170, 171 and in 5th edition (isbn13: 978-0-321-71411-4, isbn10: 0-321-71411-3 ) pages 166,167.